# Informix - unable to import the files in windows 7 64 bit

Tags: informix

I am trying to import the exported files from another DB server. DB export file size is about 780 MB. I could successfully import it in a Linux server. When I tried to import the same in my local windows machine, it throws the following error:

25582 - Network connection is broken.

54 - Connection reset by peer.

After this, local informix install crashes and could not start the Informix service. Please help.

Comment: As I said in response to your comment asking about this after your other question, the -25582 error means your server crashed while the data was being imported. That it can't be restarted is problematic; that shouldn't happen. You should probably contact IBM/Informix Tech Support. You should certainly look at your online log file to see what it says went wrong. You should, please, quote the Informix version numbers in full.  How did you transfer the data to the Windows machine? Do the files have CRLF line endings? I'd expect them to be necessary, but I've not used Informix on Windows enough.

Comment: Jon, I am using Informix 11.70 on windows.  I got export files as <dbname>.exp and I try to import using dbimport.  Almost all the tables got imported but in the middle of grant permissions, I got the above errors.